# Create a self signed certificate with keyUsage

Tags: openssl, digital-signature

I am signing a PDF's with self signed digitally signed certificate, and I am looking for a way to add the `keyUsage`([link](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#Key-Usage))
I had found [this article](http://www.mytidbitz.com/?p=109), and changed my openssl.cnf accordingly.

> req_extensions     = v3_req
>   [ v3_req ]
>   basicConstraints = CA:TRUE
>   keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment

I am using the next code to self sign a digital signatues:

> openssl  genrsa -des3 -passout pass:1234 -out aaa.private.pem -extensions v3_req
>
> openssl  req -passout pass:1234 -subj "/C=IL/ST= - /L=/O=/CN=AB" -utf8 -key aaa.private.pem -passin pass:1234 -new > aaa.cert.csr -extensions v3_req
>
> openssl  rsa -in aaa.private.pem -passin pass:1234 -out aaa.key
>
> openssl  x509 -req -days 3650 -in aaa.cert.csr -out aaa.cert -signkey aaa.key -CA myCA.ca.cert -CAkey myCA.ca.key -CAcreateserial -extensions v3_req
>
> openssl  pkcs12 -passout pass:pkcs12511260945 -export -in aaa.cert -out aaa.cert.p12 -inkey aaa.key
>
> openssl  pkcs12 -in aaa.cert.p12 -out aaa.cert.crt -password pass:1234 -nodes

While the output of the next command:

> openssl req -text -noout -in aaa.cert.csr
>   is:
>   Certificate Request:
>       Data:
>           Version: 0 (0x0)
>           Subject: C=IL, ST= - , O=45, CN=AN
>           Subject Public Key Info:
>               Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
>                   Public-Key: (2048 bit)
>                   Modulus:
>                       00:e8:0c:71:fb:b3:76:40:a4:1c:5b:45:5e:4d:b8:
>   ...
>                       60:ff:c4:52:4e:88:fe:82:2d:76:60:d2:68:73:d9:
>                   Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
>           Attributes:
>           Requested Extensions:
>               X509v3 Basic Constraints:
>                   CA:TRUE
>               X509v3 Key Usage:
>                   Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
>       Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
>            79:a3:ae:48:9a:de:02:3b:31:06:c9:f8:57:b6:1c:10:e4:c2:
>         ...
>            15:4d:4f:31:72:b8:9f:7a:d1:94:9b:05:8b:b9:fa:f4:7f:33:

## the problem

When I am using the `aaa.cert.p12` file to sign my PDF's the signature is good but acrobat reader says that "keyUsage - not specified"

I don't know what should I do...

Comment: It does not really make sense to create a CA certificate (basicConstraints = CA:TRUE) here. Have you tried FALSE?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639) They show you how to add the key usage, add the DNS names in the proper place, etc...

Comment: First of all thanks about your answer.
Second Openssl is a dev tool, you may use it in any system both linux unix and windows.
I need it to create signature to sign PDF, and I am looking for the right syntax, this is not an IT quetion.